# PHP arrays, iterating form input values

Tags: php, mysql

Absolutely losing what's left of my mind on this. I've been poring over SO for days and nothing I've tried has got me any progress ...

I have a form which includes a table where user inputs date, location, etc.:

```
<td class="date"><input class="datepicker" name="date[]" value="" /></td>
<td class="location"><input class="location" name="location[]" value="" /></td>
<td class="artist"><input class="artist" name="artist[]" value="" /></td>
<td class="artist-rep"><input class="artist-rep" name="artist-rep[]" value="" /></td>
<td class="add-delete-row">
    <a href="#" class="delete-row" title="Delete row">Delete</a>
    <a href="#" class="add-row" title="Add a row">Add Row</a>
</td>
```

The number of rows is inconstant, as user can add rows (jQuery). Each row represents a session date and if I ever get to that square, I'll INSERT them into a 'Sessions' table in the db.

I thought I'd be asking how to write the mySQL query but at this point I can't even echo the values using:

```
$date1 = $_POST['date'][0];
$date2 = $_POST['date'][1];
$date3 = $_POST['date'][2];

echo "<p class=\"debug\">date 1: " . $date1. "</p>";
echo "<p class=\"debug\">date 2: " . $date2. "</p>";
echo "<p class=\"debug\">date 3: " . $date3. "</p>";
```

(Nothing is echo'd).

I expect I'll have an array (rows) of arrays (session dates/details), but I'm just lost with php arrays, especially when my attempts to even get values to $_POST fails. And by the way, there are other fields in the form (outside the session dates table) which are $_POSTing just fine and getting into the db (a different table), so I don't understand why these inputs' values are MIA.

Any help much appreciated. I'll be on the bridge, eagerly awaiting help ... or a stiff gust of wind.

Comment: did you try a print_r of $_POST['date']?

Comment: So - do you have `form` tag? What does `print_r($_POST)` shows?

Comment: Like @Snowburnt said, run a print_r() or var_dump() of $_POST. If you get nothing, then you're missing something as basic as <form method="post"> to start out your form. If you have that, then check your form names in both your javascript that creates new form elements (using tools like Firebug helps) and your HTML files.

Comment: @u_mulder yes I have a form tag. As I said, the other form values (outside this sessions table) are $_POSTing

Comment: Do you submit the form per JavaScript or the usual way?

Comment: p.s. fwiw: if I remove the [] from the html name attribute, then print_r returns only the last date entered ...

Comment: @ragol no js used to submit the form

Comment: @Duniyadnd Thanks; I do have <form id="sessionsData" method="post" action="/html/process.php">

Comment: @Duniyadnd Yes I confirmed in Firebug that when adding rows, the input's name values are added with e.g., name="date[]", etc.

Comment: Is the datepicker class used to bind a jQuery event?

Comment: @jboneca Indeed, there was an issue with the date-picker, the result of which is that the jQuery which adds a row removes the class and ID and re-initializes each date picker with a unique ID

Comment: @jboneca P.S. and there are several other datepickers inputs in the form (outside this problematic table), and once I resolved the aforementioned issue, I succeed in getting unique values from all other datepicker instances

Comment: Yeah, I vaguely remember reading about something like that. I knew it had to be something with that, since there's no reason your above code shouldn't work. So is your issue solved?

Comment: @jboneca nope, not yet :(