# retrieving array using $_REQUEST but not $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

I've been blinding myself with `$_POST`-related problems on SO for days, still have no resolution to my problem (and it sure seems a lot of folks have issues with `$_POST`) however, following-up my question ([PHP arrays, iterating form input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917119/php-arrays-iterating-form-input-values)) with some new info:

So ... I have a form (input.php) with about a dozen fields which are `$_POST`ing no problem (to process.php), however within this form is a table for line items, to which the user can dynamically add rows as needed (the markup is a single table row, hardcoded; add'l rows added using jQuery).

So, while all the other input's values are `$_POST`ing, the values in this table are not. If, in my process page I replace `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST` for the table's values, they are retrieved, i.e.:

Pertinent excerpts from the **form page**:

```
<form id="invoiceData" name="invoiceData" method="POST" action="/html/process.php">
    <!-- SNIP (invNum input, etc.) -->
    <td class="date"><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date[]" value="" /></td>
    <td class="hours"><input type="text" class="hours" name="hours[]" value="" /></td>
    <td class="rate"><input type="text" class="rate" name="rate[]" value="" /></td>
    <td class="date-total"><input type="text" class="date-total" name="dateTotal[]" value="" /></td>
    <td class="add-delete-row">
        <a href="#" class="delete-row" title="Delete row">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="add-row" title="Add a row">Add Row</a>
    </td>
```

Pertinent excerpt from **process.php**:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        // GET $_POST VALUES FROM input.php
        $invNum = $_POST['invNum'];
        $invDate    = $_POST['invDate'];
        $projNum    = $_POST['projNum'];
        // etc., a bunch more, getting them all ...

        // ... but these, from the dynamic table within the form; $_REQUEST works but not $_POST
        for ($i = 0; $i<count($_REQUEST['date']); $i++) {
            $date = $_REQUEST['date'][$i];
            $hours = $_REQUEST['hours'][$i];
            $rate = $_REQUEST['rate'][$i];
            $dateTotal = $_REQUEST['dateTotal'][$i];

            echo "<div class=\"debug\">
                        <p>" . $i .". " . $date . ", " . $hours . ", " . $rate . ", " . $dateTotal . "</p>
                </div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

... which returns:

1. 2014-02-23, 1, 100.00, 100.00
2. 2014-02-24, 2, 100.00, 200.00
3. 2014-02-25, 3, 100.00, 300.00

So, why is `$_REQUEST` retrieving these values but not `$_POST`? Anyway, is there any reason not to move forward using `$_REQUEST` (e.g., security)? What I'm after ultimately is best practices to accomplish this kind of task, I'm open to suggestion (but especially resolution to this week of confusion). I know I have a lot of homework to do re: php arrays.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `$_REQUEST` contains everything that's in `$_POST` and `$_GET`. What does `var_dump($_POST, $_GET);` show?

Comment: `$_REQUEST` contains everything that's in `$_POST` and `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: I do not think I have ever successfully used $_POST with arrays.  I typically would create a string that is delimited by a pipe (|) character or semicolons

Comment: @Barmar var_dump($_POST, $_GET); returns all the values in the form except the values in the table, which are e.g., [date"]=> NULL ["hours"]=> NULL ["rate"]=> NULL ["dateTotal"]=> NULL

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP Thx. Can you expand on this for a php newbie? (with code example please?)

Comment: I think @SyntaxLAMP is wrong, many people use `$_POST` with arrays like this and it works fine. My guess is some other part of your script is resetting those `$_POST` variables, but is leaving the corresponding `$_REQUEST` variables alone.

Comment: I use post in conjunction with AJAX, and typically the requests are set as a string.  I suppose if you appended the formdata as an object, it could work. But using a delimited string would allow you to use the PHP explode() command to turn the string into an array

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, I've discovered the culprit: in my head.php include, I had a snippet - which I understood to be globally preventing injection. I'll post the details in an Answer, should this prove helpful to anyone else.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP It doesn't look like he's using AJAX, just normal HTML form submission. Without using Javascript that combines all the inputs  into a hidden field, there's no way to send them as a delimited string. Array-style input names deal with this automatically; PHP and other server-side CGI libraries know to convert these into arrays.

Comment: btw, why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime ago I found this and understood it to be a tactic to globally preclude sql injection:

```
// prevent SQL Injection in $_POST variables:
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)  {
    $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

It seems to also be interfering with a $_POST array, so it's got to go. I'll be reading up on sql injection prevention now, but in the meantime, if anyone can suggest a modification to this so that it will not bust my array, please chime in.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to also be interfering with a $_POST array, so it's got to go. I'll be
>   reading up on sql injection prevention now, but in the meantime, if
>   anyone can suggest a modification to this so that it will not bust my
>   array, please chime in.
>
> Thanks everyone.

You can try to check if $_POST is an array before using mysql_escape_string:

```
    // prevent SQL Injection in $_POST variables:
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)  {
      if(!is_array($_POST[$key])){        
        $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
      }
    }
```